# How to pass header to url in webview android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview and a url where I need to pass header to it.

I tried the following code but, this did not worked for me

```
WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {
          /*  @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
*/
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {

                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    Utility.printMessage("url inside..." + url);
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url1);
                    Utility.printMessage("url after..." + "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url1);
                    httpPost.setHeader("x-csrf-token", Utility.getToken(context));
                    HttpResponse httpReponse = client.execute(httpPost);

                    Header contentType = httpReponse.getEntity().getContentType();
                    Header encoding = httpReponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding();
                    InputStream responseInputStream = httpReponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    String contentTypeValue = null;
                    String encodingValue = null;
                    if (contentType != null) {
                        contentTypeValue = contentType.getValue();
                    }
                    if (encoding != null) {
                        encodingValue = encoding.getValue();
                    }
                    return new WebResourceResponse(contentTypeValue, encodingValue, responseInputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
```

I tried using Httpget method but this did not seem to work, rather i have tried passing header through map.
Can someone suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
  webView.loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> headers)
   return true;
  }

 });
```

Comment: what is WebViewChromeClient() ?

Comment: sorry , i removed that .That was in my code , not required in your case

Comment: it did not, I Actually found the issue i tried the above code earlier but the actual problem was that i used google viewer to view the pdf over the webview and hence the google viewer does not pass the header ahead.